# WCAG - should a table (row) with dynamically populated data be included in the tab order?

Tags: wcag, wcag2.0

For an app a table, that is dynamically populated with data, is important.

How should I do the tab order for tables of data? I searched for guidelines, but could not find a good one so far.

Possibilities I see are:

- Only include the table itsef using a 'tabindex=0' attribute in the 'table' tag.
- Include the table rows in the tab order with a 'tabindex=0' attribute in the 'tr' tag.

I guess using the arrow keys will allow for detail navigation.

What do you advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table itself and the rows themselves are generally **not** keyboard focusable because they're not interactive elements.  If the row was selectable or expandable, then *maybe* it could be focusable but it's usually an **element** in the table row (or more accurately, an element in a the table cell) that is selectable or expandable.

Without more details on the behavior you're trying to achieve, it's hard to give exact advice, but my initial thought is that none of the table elements proper (`<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>`) should be focusable.

Regarding arrow keys for navigation, that's the pattern for a [grid](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#grid), which is a type of table that has editable cells (similar to a spreadsheet).  Again, I don't have enough info on your situation to know if a grid is what you're trying to create.

For screen reader users, they already have a way to navigate *to* the table and navigate *within* the table using the screen reader shortcut keys, so don't worry about trying to make things focusable for screen reader users.

Answer (score 0):

Lately I heard another suggestion from an expert.

Generally speaking, all interactive elements should be included in the tab index, such as buttons, form fields and links. If the entire table row can be clicked, this should be in the tab flow by means of a tab index 0.